# action if all class have a specific status

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I am trying to build a script that will be triggered as soon as:

- within the DIV with class="eventIndicator", the span has a class "validated" (currently "unvalidated")

AND

- the parent of DIV with class="evenIndicator" has a style="display: block;" (currently style="display: none;"

As an example, I have added a small extract of my code.

Do you think it is possible? I have a tried with Jquery but couldn't succeed.
Thanks for your help.

```
<div id="hidden3">
    <div id="asset_parameters">
        <div id="Rente_div" style="display: none;">
            <span>Rente:</span>
            <span><input name="Rente" id="Rente" onblur="asset_value(this.id)"></span>
            <div class="eventIndicator">
                <span class="unvalidated">Incomplete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Bouquet_div"  style="display: none;">
            <span>Bouquet:</span>
            <span><input name="Bouquet" id="Bouquet" onblur="asset_value(this.id)"></span>
            <div class="eventIndicator">
                <span class="unvalidated">Incomplete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Valeur_libre_div"  style="display: none;">
            <span>Valeur libre:</span>
            <span><input name="Valeur_libre" id="Valeur_libre" onblur="asset_value(this.id)"></span>
            <div class="eventIndicator">
                <span class="unvalidated">Incomplete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want something to run whenever the DOM changes, and take action if the conditions are true? There's no DOM change event, you need to find something else to trigger the check.

Comment: Where is the extract of your code? You've just posted the HTML, not any of the jQuery you tried to write.

Comment: Hi Barmar. I thought it was possible to have a jquery in the background that could trigger it. So basically, i need to find another trigger event... I don't have any jquery to post as what I wrote does not work. thanks

Comment: That's what AlienWebguy's answer does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could poll it but it's not very efficient. I'd fire a callback instead, but here's a polling snippet:

```
(function poll () {
    var $div = $('.eventIndicator');
    if ($div.find('span.validated').length && $div.parent().is(':visible')) {
        // do something
    } else {
        setTimeout(poll, 500);
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toggleClass()` when an event fires. The bottom line is that an event has to fire in order for something to happen.

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger your own event on every `show` / `hide` usage and then count the visible elements:

```
if($('#Rente_div:visible, #Bouquet_div:visible, #Valeur_libre_div:visible').length === 3) alert('OK')
```

or you can just use `setInterval` to check this

// edit: oops sorry - this post was made for your previous version of question
but I guess you can adjust this answer for your needs